# TypeError: assert.equal is not a function

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js, truffle

I created solidity contracts and compiled it with truffle successfully but when I run truffle test for test files of my contracts it gives the error

> TypeError: assert.equal is not a function

my code

```
const { assert } = require('console');

const Tether = artifacts.require('Tether.sol');
const RWD = artifacts.require('RWD');
const DecentralBank = artifacts.require('DecentralBank');

require('chai')
.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
.should()

contract('DecentralBank', ([owner, customer]) => {
    let tether, rwd, decentralBank;

    function  tokens(number) {
        return web3.utils.toWei(number, 'ether')
    }

    before(async () => {
        tether = await Tether.new()
        rwd = await RWD.new()
        decentralBank = await DecentralBank.new(rwd.address, tether.address)

       await rwd.transfer(decentralBank.address, tokens('1000000'));

       await tether.transfer(customer, tokens('100'),{from: owner});
    })

    describe('Tether', async () =>{
        it('matches name successfully', async () => {
            const name = await tether.name()
            console.log(name)
            assert.equal(name, 'Tether')
        })
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong `assert`. you do not need this

```
const { assert } = require('console');
```

You probably automatically imported by mistake when typed `assert`. Truffle uses mocha and `assert` is globally available.